# Copy using Javascript returns extra line feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, copy

I am copying content from a tag using range, which returns perfect content on Chrome. But not in Firefox, which gives a new line on starting.

HTML element:

```
<p>I am on the wall
I am on the earth
I am on the another earth</p>
```

code :

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(element);
//range.selectNodeContents(element);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Chrome:

```
I am on the wall
I am on the earth
I am on the another earth
```

Firefox:

```
[new line feed in here]    
I am on the wall
I am on the earth
I am on the another earth
```

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 0):

use `<br>` as the line break instead of while spaces in HTML. If it's not working, it's better to use a [javascriptToolTipPlugin](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20tooltip%20plugin)

Comment: Actually, the content copied successfully as it is. But a new line introduced in the beginning when tried it on Firefox.